# How to get user information after submition user info in registration form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the firebase authentication system in my react app. Everything was fine, I got user data by submission. The problem is I do not get displayName in real-time. When I refresh the page, I get it where I get the email without refreshing it.

I want to get email and displayName as well.

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState({});
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(() => {
        updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: name,
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError(new Error("Sorry !! Couldn't find user !!"));
      });

    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the display name of the user does not change their authentication state, so your `onAuthStateChanged` handler won't get notified of this change.

Calling `updateProfile` updates the user profile on the server, but (iirc) also does not immediately update the user profile in the client. To do that you'll want to reload the user profile, and then pass it to your rendering code by calling `setCurrentUser`.

So something like:

```
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: name,
}).then(() => {
  auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
    setCurrentUser(auth.currentUer);
  })
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I do not get name in real-time.